# Redis Cache Pub Sub delete after receive

Tags: redis, publish-subscribe

Is there a way to delete a message from a subscriber, once it is received by that subscriber so as to prevent it from being read by another subscriber to the same channel?

Note: this behavior is supported on Azure Service Bus..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NO, you cannot do that with Redis pubsub.

However, you can achieve the goal with [Redis Stream](https://redis.io/topics/streams-intro). You can create a consumer group with the `XGROUP CREATE` command. For each message in a Redis Stream, only one consumer in the group can read the message. Check [this](https://redis.io/commands/xreadgroup#consumer-groups-in-30-seconds) for detail.